# Periodically sending vars to PHP page automatically

Tags: php, timer, refresh

Every 4 seconds I am refreshing a php page and it updates the time. 
Each time this happens I want to send the time to another page but NOT navigate away from the page 
that is refreshing the time...

Below is some sample code:

```
<?

$target = mktime(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) ;
header('refresh:4; url=timer.php');
$today = (int)(time ());

$siteToReceiveTime = "http://www.nbit.co.za/toriggo/receive.php?time=$today";

print "time in $today seconds";

?>
```

Comment: Why not just store it to database?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you could do this...
Ajax being one - that could handle the every 4 seconds bit and would be able to make requests without changing the page.
The other option would be with [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)...

Answer (score 1):

Read the [CURL function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). You can have PHP call CURL to load the page for you from the PHP script without interfering with your users.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_get_contents("http://www.nbit.co.za/toriggo/receive.php?time=$today");
```